# flag/argument in bash alias

Tags: bash

I want to write an alias as such:

```
alias add="java -jar vc.jar name"
```

Is there a way I can use a wildcard for name and thus only have to type:
add name - with name being any name of my choice?  name being an argument.

Comment: Note that you should probably use an absolute path rather than the relative `vc.jar`, otherwise your alias will only work when invoked from a specific location.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are looking for [functions](https://ss64.com/bash/function.html).

```
 function add() {
   local name="$1"
   java -jar vc.jar "${name}"
 }
```

Add this to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` and just call like this;

```
user@host$ add samplename
```

Alternatively you can trigger an alias expansion by adding a space or tab character at the end of the alias definition.

```
alias add='java -jar vc.jar '
```

(Note the space at the end of definition).

Then just call it normally;

```
user@host$ add samplename
```

It should work.

**EDIT:**
As pointed out by [@kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/116858/kusalananda) you can omit the space and it will still work just fine.

Comment: The space at the end of the alias should not be needed.

Comment: The space at the end of the alias is to trigger alias expansion of the *next* word. In `foo bar`, if `foo` is an alias ending with space, then `bar` is also checked for alias expansion.

Comment: They refer to wildcards in the question, which hints at filename expansion. Assuming that's what they intend to use, it's worth noting that the function here only uses its first argument, i.e. `add *.txt` just uses the first matching filename.

Comment: Adding the function above works, adding a space at the end of the line works as well..Thanks!

Comment: If that works please mark as the answer for reference of others

Answer (score 5):

You can try to remove the `name` flag and set an alias for `java -jar vc.jar`.

What you want to do:

```
alias add="java -jar vc.jar"
```

You now have set an alias. To run it:

```
add nameofsomethingyouwant
```

You could also try it with @cevhyruz's solution, but I think this one is simpler.

Comment: What's the `su` for?

Comment: @Kusalananda I don't really know, I just always have super user on my when I'm working in a terminal. 
Maybe if your permissions are not default, this could help or something. You don't have to do the `su` part. It's just a habit of me.

Comment: Um, you have a _habit_ to work as root in the terminal?!

Comment: @Kusalananda yup, always root

Comment: @Kusalananda but it does work, doesn't it?

Comment: There is absolutely _no_ reason to change into root to run a Java program. Habitually working at an interactive root shell is _not_ a practice that I would condone.

Comment: @Kusalananda the root is only for the alias though, I'll remove the `su` part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83671/discussion-between-sam-and-kusalananda).

Comment: Running only the `alias` as root would be pointless, because as soon as you exited the root shell, the definition would be lost. So the *only* reason to use `su` (or `sudo`) here would be because you needed *the Java command itself* to run with administrative privileges.